# TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I get the following error while trying to create a command in a cog
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
with code and the feature is simple when you initiate the command, it will send the user a certain set of questions then return the answers they give into an embed where the command was initiated

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



class Profile(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Profile Cog has been loaded\n-----")

    # @commands.command(aliases=['pm'])
    # async def dm(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    #   message = message or "This message is sent via dm"
    #   await user.send(message)
    #   await ctx.message.delete()

    @commands.command()
    async def createprofile(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        userName = ""
        userAge = ""
        questions = [
            "Please input your name/nickname:",
            "Please input your age:"
        ]
        dmChannel = await ctx.author.send(
            "Yo will be receiving two questions. One involving your name and the other your age.")

        def check(message):
            return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == dmChannel.channel

        async def askquestion(question):
            await ctx.author.send(question)
            print("Waiting for reply...")
            userReply = await commands.wait_for('message', check=check)
            print("User replied")
            return userReply.content

        userName = await askquestion(questions[0])
        userAge = await askquestion(questions[1])
        e = discord.Embed(title=str(userName) + "'s Profile", description=f"""
        Age: `{str(userAge)}`
        """)
        await ctx.send(embed=e)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Profile(bot))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dargo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dargo\Desktop\In-Depth\cogs\profile.py", line 42, in createprofile
    userName = await askquestion(questions[0])
  File "C:\Users\dargo\Desktop\In-Depth\cogs\profile.py", line 38, in askquestion
    userReply = await commands.wait_for('message', check=check)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
``
```

Comment: You must include the _full_ stacktrace, including the actual line of code that threw the error. Your code ideally should be a [mre]. If we can't run your code or see where the error is, you're basically expecting us to stare at your code and have the error somehow become obvious and jump out at us, which I think most people would prefer not to do if they don't have to.

Comment: i have provided the full error, and the code is for the cog no other errors come up

Answer (score 0):

don't use `member: discord.Member = None` in your args but do something like:

`member: discord.Member = ""` and after in the effective code write for example:

```py
if member == "":
 #do something
else:
 #do something else
```

Comment: but the issue with that is, there is no else I would need. it sends the question and waits for a reply then returns the content into the embed. but I do not get past the first question because of the error

Comment: Yes I have used different functions, running the wait for under try/except/finally and I have run the code under different ides and text editors no errors at all until the user trys to reply and it gives the none type cant be used in await function error

Comment: have you tried with replacing `commands.wait_for` with `self.client.wait_for`?

Comment: thank you so much that actually did work, I do not know why commands.wait_for doesn't apply and throws the error.

Comment: nice i'm happy for you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226589/discussion-between-jango-darkwind-and-polliog).